# Error when executing step 'qmake' on Mac Os

Tags: qt, macos

I have just purchased a Macbook (yes I am a complete noob on Mac though I have some considerable experience with Linux) and I'm trying to build my Qt application on it. I have installed XCode and the Qt SDK but when I try to build my project on Qt Creator all I get is the following error during qmake:

```
Running build steps for project TimeTracker...
Starting: "/usr/bin/qmake" /Users/raphaelcruzeiro/Documents/Projects/Timely/Widget/TimeTracker/TimeTracker.pro -r -spec macx-g++
Failure to open file: /Developer/Applications/Qt/Makefile
Unable to generate makefile for: /Users/raphaelcruzeiro/Documents/Projects/Timely/Widget/TimeTracker/TimeTracker.pro
The process "/usr/bin/qmake" exited with code %2.
Error while building project TimeTracker (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'qmake'
```

Any ideas on what is going on? /Developer/Applications/Qt/Makefile indeed does not exist.

EDIT:

Ok, I know what is going on but I don't know how to fix it. When I ran qmake from the terminal everything went just fine. I believe that Qt Creator is trying to build my application on the Qt directory itself and it does nt have permission for it (it shouldn't anyway).
How do I tell Qt Creator where to build my application? I didn't find it anywhere and setting the DESTDIR variable isn't helping.

THE SOLUTION:

Deleting the .pro.user file made Qt Creator build the application to the directory specified in DESTDIR

Comment: You should change your solution to be an answer to the question.

Comment: Agreed. Posting it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THE SOLUTION:

Deleting the .pro.user file made Qt Creator build the application to the directory specified in DESTDIR

Answer (score 0):

I was battling with the same thing. What helped eventually was resetting the default build directory here:

[image]